# Thread causing error message on leaving and comes back to game app

Tags: android, multithreading

After hitting home after playing my threaded game then hitting the apps icon, then hitting the icon for my app again, I get a "digger has quit unexpectedly error" and it brings me back to the general apps screen, I can hit my app icon again at this point and it brings me to the game and it runs fine. I expect there is something I should be doing with the thread to prevent that irritating message when I restart my app. maybe in an `onStop` or `onPause` method. here is my thread code fragments:

```
getHolder().addCallback(
    new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        //@Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            boolean retry = true;
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    gameLoopThread.join();
                    retry = false;
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }

        //@Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            screenWidth =gameView.getWidth(); 
            screenHeight = gameView.getHeight(); 
            createSprites();
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
            gameLoopThread.start();
        }

        //@Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
            int width, int height) {
        }
    });
```

I have a gamethread class with this:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
public class GameLoopThread extends Thread {

    static final long FPS = 10;
    private GameView view;
    private boolean running = false;
    public GameLoopThread(GameView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        running = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long ticksPS = 200 / FPS;
        long startTime;
        long sleepTime;
        while (running) {
            Canvas c = null;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                    view.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
            sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            try {
                if (sleepTime > 0)
                    sleep(sleepTime);
                else
                    sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

one thing I tried was changing the surfaceDestroyed method to just;

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
}
```

but that didn't help.

Comment: What platform is this?  Android?  It should be tagged as such.

Comment: This is a lot of poorly formatted code, you might want to format it a little more cleanly.

Comment: Also, the app will generate the error message for a reason. Check the log and add the stacktrace to your question.